# Is there a free software that stores all logs (checkboxes) and actions taken of the Development team?

Tags: tfs, jira

Is there a free software that stores all logs (checkboxes) and actions taken of the Development team?

1. When was the task assigned.
2. Actions taken on the task
3. Dependencies on the task
4. Cause of Delays
5. Status
6. Delivered Date

Like a TFS or Jira.

Comment: Should it be a web application? By "free software" I guess you mean it costs nothing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like a TFS or Jira

Then, it sounds like you are looking for [YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/).

It is excellent and full-featured. Free up to 10 users. Canbe self-hosted, which is how we use it, or they will host.

[reasonly priced](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/buy/#incloud?billing=yearly) for more than 10 uers.

- When was the task assigned  ✅
- Actions taken on the task   ✅
- Dependencies on the task    ✅
- Cause of Delays             ✅
- Status                      ✅
- Delivered Date              ✅

Lots of images follow, but please visit the site to explore the full functionality. I honestly see it as a competitor to Jira (made by JetBrains, who make the best IDEs). It has 45,000 customers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great!!!

Comment: I am glad to hear that you agree. A total Jira replacement. We use it hosted by them, but I also use it at home, on my own server (Apache, running on my laptop) for my own single developer projects.  Check out their IDES - simply the best, ***and*** PyCHarm for Python is free for commercial use. Spread the word (I am not in any way associated with JetBrains)